# How can I get wifi on virtual machines for Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, virtualization, kali-linux

I want to connect my virtual machine (running Kali Linux) to wifi networks so I can do testing on the network (not through NAT). I have a Asus USB-AC56 wireless adapter but even with this I cannot seem to get wifi and so no wlan0 on programs that need that.

I have tried both Virtual Box and VMware environments.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

To do so safely you need to allocate the entire USB controller to the VM using PCI passthrough. Make sure you have IOMMU support (on Intel it's called VT-d) so your hypervisor can properly isolate the device.

USB ins't ideal in this case because you're assigning all associated USB port to this VM.

Answer (score -1):

Install **Guest Additions** in Kali Linux. Then the usb should shop up in your virtual box.

I was facing the same problem months ago. This solution worked for me.

Make sure your USB WLAN supports Linux environment. You can go to their website to check. Also check if it requires to have drivers installed in order to use it.